# Peak detection from image analysis data using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, max, signal-processing

I worked with IMAGE processing to detect boundary of an image and get coordinates (x,y) and then polar coordinates (theta,rho). Now I need to work with SIGNAL processing to detect peaks in these data and especially display/plot peaks as points (red stars or something..) How it works between each other, I mean signal and image toolbox?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: This question is contains multiple questions (peak estimation, graph plotting, image processing). @martin, I suggest you edit the question to make it more specific and to provide more details about the context.

Comment: @knedlsepp - That duplicate was good, but I found a more suitable one... what's funny is that both links I provided an answer to lol.

Comment: Finally I inspired from: http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/peak-analysis.html and I have these results: http://www.nahraj-obrazek.cz/?di=314247002841 Does somebody know what is wrong? My code is: BW=im2bw(I);
BWH=imfill(BW,'holes'); 
BWE=edge(BWH,'canny'); 
boundaries=bwboundaries(BWE); 
b=boundaries; x=b(:,2); y=b(:,1); 
% cartesian plot 
X=x-mean(x); 
Y=y-mean(y); 
THETA=X; 
RHO=Y; 
[THETA,RHO]=cart2pol(X,Y); 
% polar plot 
RHO1=smooth(RHO,10); 
% smoothing data 
plot(RHO1);

Comment: MY CODE IS: BW=im2bw(I);
BWH=imfill(BW,'holes'); 
BWE=edge(BWH,'canny'); 
boundaries=bwboundaries(BWE); 
b=boundaries; x=b(:,2); y=b(:,1); 
% cartesian plot 
X=x-mean(x); 
Y=y-mean(y); 
THETA=X; 
RHO=Y; 
[THETA,RHO]=cart2pol(X,Y); 
% polar plot 
RHO1=smooth(RHO,10); 
% smoothing data 
plot(RHO1); t=1:length(RHO1); [~,locs_Rwave]=findpeaks[RHO1]; RHO_inverted=-RHO1; [~,locs_Swave]=findpeaks[RHO_inverted]; figure;hold on;plot(t,RHO1); plot (locs_Rwave,RHO1(locs_Rwave)); plot(locs_Swave,RHO1(locs_Swave));grid on;

Comment: I changed somewhere accidentaly brackets..